# Set number of columns in pdftable

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

I want to display only **5 columns** in a page and remaining columns in **next page** in **pdftable**. Can we set the number of columns in a pdftable? Please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this [PdfPTable constructor](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html#PdfPTable(int)):

> `public PdfPTable(int numColumns)`
>
> Constructs a PdfPTable with `numColumns` columns.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - numColumns - the number of columns

Hence if you want to create a `PdfPTable` with 5 columns, you would need to create your `PdfPTable` like this:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5);
```

Of course, if you already have a `PdfPTable` with more columns, then you can not just add that table with the following line:

```
document.add(table);
```

The above line will add all the columns.

If you want to add only 5 columns of a table that has more columns, you need to take control over the layout. Your only resort is to use the `writeSelectedRows()` method.

You can find an example on how to use this method [here](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=90):

```
float newY = table.writeSelectedRows(0, 5, 0, -1, 36, 806, canvas);
```

This method will render the first 5 columns of the table (that's what the parameters `0` and `5` are about) and all the rows (that's what the parameters `0` and `-1` are about; `-1` means: up until the last row). We add the table at a position `x = 36` and `y = 806` to the direct content (`canvas`).

However: as you are taking *full control* over the table, you are responsible to make sure that the table fits on the page. For instance: if not all the rows fit on the page, then the table will go on beyond the visible area of the page.

To avoid this, you should calculate the height of each row first.

Also: if a table doesn't cover the complete page, you'll have to keep track of the Y position. In the above code snippet, the Y position at the end of the table is `newY`.

Any subsequent `document.add()` operation will **not** be aware of this `newY`, so it's important to understand that switching to *absolute positioning* means that you can no longer count on iText to do the positioning automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will be having a dynamic number of columns and need to print 5 columns per page. Sometimes there will be only 2 columns and some times more than 5 upto 50. So is this possible??.. Please give me a reply.

Comment: The reply is: yes, it is possible. I have already answered how you can do this: use `writeSelectedRows()` to position the columns on each page.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Why there is no set method for no of Columns?. I would like to create no of columns dynamically based on the data. I would like to create the PdfPTable object then later set the number of columns based on the data. Currently I am doing it like this. Create a `PdfPTable` with just 1 column. Later based on the data create another object with no of columns and assign to earlier object.

Comment: I have same questions as Balaji. How do I dynamically specify no of columns

Comment: @Geek You're commenting on a question dating from 2015. Don't expect an answer, especially since the answer is already there: You can create a `PdfPTable` with any value you like for the `numColumns` parameter.

Comment: btw I found it I am reading excel file using POI and it has the function my_worksheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); Though each row can have a different no of columns, but for my use case in which no of colums are constant this is working just fine

Answer (score 0):

## Create Table and Get Number of Columns from PdfPTable

==> Create Function or method GenerateFile()

```
 void GenerateFile()
    {

   string path = Application.dataPath + "/myfirstfile.pdf"; 
    if (File.Exists(path)) File.Delete(path);
    
//Create Document 
        var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        var document = new Document(PageSize.A4,10f,10f,10f,0f);
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fileStream);
        document.Open();
        document.NewPage();
        var baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, 
        BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

//Create Table


 int noOfcoloumn = 5;
    PdfPTable mytable = new PdfPTable(noOfcoloumn);
    mytable .AddCell("Order ID"); //Row 1 Strat
    mytable .AddCell("Order Time");
    mytable .AddCell("User");
    mytable .AddCell("Order Status");
    mytable .AddCell("View");

    mytable .AddCell("OID3242");  //Row 2 Strat
    mytable .AddCell("04/03/2021 14:50:51");  
    mytable .AddCell("Atul R Patel"); 
    mytable .AddCell("Delivered"); 
    mytable .AddCell("ShowOrderItem"); 
        


  //Debug.Log("Total Number of Columns:-- " +table.NumberOfColumns);//[In Unity //Debuging]

    
    document.Add(mytable); // Add in to pdf file
    document.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
    
    Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph(string.Format("Total Number of Columns : {0}", 
    mytable.NumberOfColumns ));
    p1.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    document.Add(p1);
    document.Close();
    writer.Close();
```

}
[image]